# Dynamic query Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

So I have next situation:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE ?2 like %?1%")
Page<Ticket> searchBy(String keyword,String property,Pageable pageable);
```

It's don't search for anything.
But like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.name LIKE %?1%")
Page<Ticket> searchBy(String keyword, String property, Pageable pageable);
```

work.

It should work like this: the client sends me a keyword and a field to search for, but the field cannot be dynamically used, then it does not search for anything. Can I insert a property dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid `@Query` doesn't allow dynamic query in any reasonable way.